# Using cvGet2D function - opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Helo, 
I dont know where is error/ I think it is connected with cvGet2D function but where is sth wrong??

```
  IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("car1.jpg",0);
  CvScalar s;

  for(int i=0;i<img->height;i++)
  {
      for(int j=0;j<img->width;j++)
      {
          s = cvGet2D(img,i,j);
      }
  }
```

---

After some time there is info Process returned -1073741819 <0xC0000005>

Answer (score 0):

You also forgot to say exactly what's the problem.

I'll assume you didn't test the result of `cvLoadImage()` and the application crashed at the first `for` loop:

```
IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("car1.jpg",0);
if (!img) 
{
    printf("!!! Failed to load image\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: sorry for the downvote, but please don't *help* noobs shooting their foot again and again, *please!*

Comment: please stop that evil cascade, they all are using this, because they've seen recent 'answers', that make using the dead stuff look like a valid approach. it is not!

Answer (score 0):

since you're obviously new to opencv, please, you *must* use it's c++ api, not the deprecated c-one.

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("car1.jpg", 0); // this will read a grayscale - 1channel image.
if ( img.empty() )
{
    // whaa, file not found
    return -1;
}

for(int i=0; i<img.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<img.cols; j++)
    {
        uchar s = img.at<uchar>(i,j);
    }
}
```