# What does Get?D(ex: Get2D) do in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

According to the documentation, Get?D "returns a specific array element" based on a bunch of "zero-based components of the elements index" but I don't understand what this actually does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get?D is the old OpenCV C API to get a single element from a Matrix.
The up to date c++ way for doing the same thing, using a cv::Mat container, is the at() method.

For example (for the 2 dimensional case, hence two indexes - i and j):
The following is returning the element (CvScalar) in the i'th column and j'th row:

```
Get2D(array,i,j)
```

This is the same as the c++ way (assuming the element type is float)

```
mat->at<float>(i,j)
```

For 3 dimensional arrays/matrices you need to supply 3 indexes, and so on...

Please see [Using cvGet2D function - opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573187/using-cvget2d-function-opencv), which is kind of a duplicate...

Comment: Thanks for the help!